# React Native Pod issue with use_native_modules

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods

I have a react native project which is for both iOS and Android.
I recently updated to react 17.0.2 and react-native 0.67.2 whilst developing for Android on my Windows machine. I have everything running and building fine in Android.

Jumping over to my mac and cloning my repo, I'm then doing the following...

```
cd ./ios
pod update
```

Doing so produces the following output...

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] /usr/local/bin/node -e try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e) {console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);}

/Users/cwd/Desktop/ReactApps/MYAPPNAME/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:350
  processRequest = (req, res, next) => {
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
.

 #  from /Users/cwd/Desktop/ReactApps/MYAPPNAME/ios/Podfile:9
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'MyApp' do
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I get the exact same result when doing `pod install`

Prior to this, I was building the app in xcode and running it on my device without any issues.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this by updating to the latest version of Node.

Comment: You are a hero, don’t let anyone tell you differently. (Worked for me upgrading from 0.64 to 0.70)